# UTF-8 character is not proper in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, character-encoding, jlabel

Please find the below sample code, The UTF-8 character properly displaying in  windows machine. But, its not proper for Linux machine (Ubuntu).

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class JContPaneTest 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\u30c7\u30fc\u30bf\u30d9\u30fc\u30b9\u304c\u898b\u3064\u304b\u308a\u307e\u305b\u3093\u3002\u30c7\u30fc\u30bf\u30d9\u30fc", "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: *"But, its not proper for Linux machine (Ubuntu)."*  What do you see on Ubuntu?  Polka dots, squares, stars..?

Comment: @AndrewThompson squares.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a character encoding problem.  More likely that some fonts are missing.

Comment: @StephenC how can i solve this problem ? do you have any sample code or document ? pls send me. it would great helpful for me.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 12.04/OpenJDK; check `Language Support` and `java -version`.

Comment: @spk - I'm saying it is not a problem with your code.  It is a mismatch between the font you are using and the character.  The square most likely means that the font doesn't have a glyph for those codepoints.  Check your installation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has nothing to do with UTF-8 or any other encoding (except that \uxxxx escapes are technically UTF-16).

Comment: @VGR The "MS Gothic" font solved this problem. Anyway, thanks for your  suggetion.

Answer (score 2):

Not all fonts contain the full unicode set of glyphs.   The blobs are probably the result of a deficient font, but in java it's hard to determine what font is actually being used, and I don't know a way to determine if these blobs are being emitted except by seeing them.

I had huge problems with unicode in pop-up menus, which probably is a very similar problem
to yours.

2 things to try.

1) Write a font test to display your string in all fonts that are available to java.
2) Try using a non-swing component.  Non-swing components use the underlying OS font support.